# How to create new project in Android Studio 1.0 Without appcompat-v7

Tags: android, android-studio

I recently upgraded to `Android Studio 1.0.1`.

When I create a new project (even if I set the minimum `SDK` to 14 or above) the `appcompat-v7` is included in my project. I want to use the holo themes and new action bar functionality so I want to create a project without the `appcompat-v7` support included How do I do this?

Previously I was running version 0.8 something. When I created a new project in `0.8` and set the minimum `SDK` to 14 or above it did it automatically?

Any suggestions?

Cheers